# Upside-down Windows OSK and Webbrowser

Tags: wpf, rotation, touch, browser, on-screen-keyboard

At my internship was requested that I'd look into utilizing the Windows OSK (**win 7/8**) for a **touch dual browser**.

After my experiences with the WPF webbrowser and extended research, I doubt this'll work. So do any of you know a way to...

**1**: Get an **upside-down webbrowser component**, with the same features as the standard IE webbrowser? (**downloading, plugins, touch navigation**) (And yes I've tried awesomium, only to find that it falls short)

**2**: Get **an OSK**, which can be turned **upside-down**, that supports **as many languages as the windows OSK**?

**It needs to be in WPF or another C# based language that offers component rotation.**

Thanks either way.

Comment: May I ask what problems did you find with Awesomium?

Comment: No touch support, No download manager, A lot of sites not being properly rendered.